# Textbox cursor in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**How can i change the mouse pointer of textbox in to hand symbol.**
I am using Visual web Developer.
my intension is to have a textbox (with database value) to be placed inside the repeater's header division for allignment purpose.i made border style to none.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create one css and assign that css to textbox.

```
<style>
.txtclass{cursor:pointer;}
</style>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="txtclass" runat="server" />
```

That's it.

Hope it helps you.

**EDIT :**

```
<style>
.txtclass input[disabled="disabled"] {
     // your color style
}
</style>
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. what should i do to change the line inside the textbox on click.If i put enable = false then the text will be white.Instead of that is there any way.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you. Can you please describe again?

Comment: I want the textbox to be non editable. I can use Enable=False But the colour of the text inside the textbox will be light even if i change the fore colour of the text box.Is it possible..?

Comment: sorry...to make it clear .Textbox must be non editable but the fore colour of text must be normal.

Comment: Do one thing, search in google for this problem, there are lots of alternative available for this. but problem is they are browser dependent. Check all any one should work for you.